# How to detect anomalies in seasonal time series sensor data?

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm struggling with detecting anomalies in time series sensor data. My data looks like this:

```
| Timestamp           | Temperature |
| 2018-04-01 10:00:00 |  19.00      |
| 2018-04-01 11:00:00 |  21.00      |
| 2018-04-01 12:00:00 |  22.00      |
```

I'm also able to provide a label, but this label isn't very accurate:

```
| Timestamp           | Temperature | IsBroken |
| 2018-04-01 10:00:00 | 19.00       | 0        |
| 2018-04-01 11:00:00 | 21.00       | 0        |
| 2018-04-01 12:00:00 | 01.00       | 1        |
```

I can also provide other sensors in the region, like humidity sensors, etc. Or the average temperature in the region.

I found so many resources about algorithms but I don't know how to solve this technically. Can somebody help me or at least push me in the right direction?

The goal is to detect if a sensor is broken or not in future sensordata based on results of the past.

Comment: What is the question, really? How do you define an "anomaly", within what parameters? What does "Broken" mean, where does it come from, and why is it not accurate?

Comment: This question is probably better suited on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ (or by reading a book on basic statistics). If you known what you you want to implement and are struggeling with the concrete implementation of your algorithm in your chosen programming language, please ask a new question here.

Comment: IsBroken means that the sensor is manualy marked as broken in the passt and manualy set to IsBroken = 0 if the sensor has been repaired. Because it's manualy marked as broken (or not) it's not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Outlier and anomaly detection is a broad topic. If you are looking for something easy to understand yet powerful try an **isolation forest** ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#isolation-forest)). This algorithm should be able to find days where the sensors reported some unusual combination of values.